# drawLine() in ImageView with stroke width of SeekBar changes

Tags: android, android-imageview, seekbar

I am drawing line in `ImageView` with `SeekBar` progress change event. If the `SeekBar` is changed incrementally it seems works fine. While decreasing the seek bar progress, the already drawn line is retained. How can I draw the line with appropriate stroke from `SeekBar` progress change event event if the decrease progress. I tried to set the `ImageView`'s drawable to `null`, and also image bitmap to `null`, still facing the error.

```
@Override       
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     
    imageCanvas.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100, paint);                 
    mStrokeWidth = (float)progress;
    imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    paint.setColor(mStrokeColor);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
    imageCanvas.drawLine(20, 20, 100, 100, paint);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue have been fixed for creating new bitmap and assign that to canvas in the onProgressChanged() method.

```
@Override       
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) 
{
  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)imageViewSize , (int) imageViewSize, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  imageCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  imageCanvas.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100, paint);                 
  mStrokeWidth = (float)progress;
  imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
  paint.setColor(mStrokeColor);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
  imageCanvas.drawLine(20, 20, 100, 100, paint);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```